# jquery appending and prepending extra quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an 'about' section and I'm trying to pull quotes off to the side.  I surround the text I want to pull off to the side with `<span class='pq'>`My quote is in here`</span>`.  I have 3 instances where I pull quotes off to the side.  The first instance adds 3 sets of quotes, the second adds 2 sets of quotes, and the 3rd and final adds the correct 1 set of quotes.

I'm still learning jQuery, but here's what I came up with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span.pq').each(function(){
        var quote = $(this).clone();
        quote.removeClass('pq');
        quote.addClass('pullquote');
        $(this).before(quote);
        $('.pullquote')
            .prepend('<span class="pq">&ldquo;</span>')
            .append('<span class="pq">&rdquo;</span>');
    })//end each
});//end ready
```

Comment: JS seems unnecessary for this... Are you sure you can't accomplish this with just CSS pseudo-elements, or maybe a sprite and position the background-image?

Comment: @elclanrs I'm not really sure what you mean.  Is there an example you can point me to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're prepending and appending the spans on each `.pullquote` element on each iteration of the `each()` loop over the `span.pq` elements. You should instead put that code outside of the `each()`, as it will operate on every `.pullquote` element. Something like this (note: untested, may need changes):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span.pq').each(function(){
        var quote = $(this).clone();
        quote.removeClass('pq');
        quote.addClass('pullquote');
        $(this).before(quote);            
    })//end each
    $('.pullquote')
        .prepend('<span class="pq">&ldquo;</span>')
        .append('<span class="pq">&rdquo;</span>');
});//end ready
```

Answer (score 1):

For quotes there are actually 2 standard HTML tags for this that carry the sematic meaning of a quote, `<q>` for a short (inline) quote and `<blockquote>` for a longer quote. CSS pseudo-elements can be used to prepend and append a quote to each of these tags.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yFY9W/)

**HTML**

```
<q>hello world</q>
<blockquote>A much longer quote... A much longer quote... A much longer quote... A much longer quote... A much longer quote...</blockquote>
```

**CSS**

```
q:before,
q:after,
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
    content:'"';
}
```